# Get drawable by string

Tags: android, android-resources, android-drawable

I parse image name by json, and now for displaying I would have to get the drawable id by the image name so I can do this:

```
background.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.eventimage1);
```

When I get the image name the format is like this:

```
image_ev1.png
```

Comment: ok so whats the question? seems that this can be solved by using if/else statements

Comment: @tyczj how can it be done? I need to convert `image_ev1.png` in to resources int -> `R.drawable.image_ev1`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use this function to get a drawable when you have the image name. Note that the image name does not include the file extension.

```
public static Drawable GetImage(Context c, String ImageName) {
        return c.getResources().getDrawable(c.getResources().getIdentifier(ImageName, "drawable", c.getPackageName()));
}
```

then just use `setBackgroundDrawable` method.

If you only want the ID, leave out the getDrawable part
i.e.

```
return c.getResources().getIdentifier(ImageName, "drawable", c.getPackageName());
```

Comment: As getDrawable() has become deprecated, better use ContextCompate.getDrawable. It gives something like `return ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, context.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", context.getPackageName()));`

Comment: Depends if you are using the V4 Support Libs.or not. Other options are available depending on need.

Comment: Good answer, but code outdated, I have also answered above in Kotlin.

Answer (score 2):

this gets you your image id

```
    int resId = getResources().
getIdentifier(your_image_name.split("\\.")[0], "drawable", getApplicationInfo().packageName);
```

if you need a drawable after that :

```
getResources().getDrawable(resId)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this method to your code:

```
protected final static int getResourceID
(final String resName, final String resType, final Context ctx)
{
    final int ResourceID =
        ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, resType,
            ctx.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
    if (ResourceID == 0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException
        (
            "No resource string found with name " + resName
        );
    }
    else
    {
        return ResourceID;
    }
}
```

Then retrieve your image so:

```
Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
background.setBackgroundResource(getResourceID("image_ev1", "drawable", ctx)));
```

Answer (score 1):

For Kotlin programmer (ContextCompat from API 22):

```
 var res = context?.let { ContextCompat.getDrawable(it,resources.getIdentifier("your_resource_name_string", "drawable", context?.getPackageName())) }
```

Your can also use e.g. "mipmap" instead of "drawable" if resource is place in other location.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do in Kotlin :

```
// FilePath : ../drawable/app_my_bg_drawable.xml    
// Call function as: val fileIntId = getDrawableIntByFileName(context, "app_my_bg_drawable")
fun getDrawableIntByFileName(context: Context, fileName: String): Int {
    return context.resources.getIdentifier(fileName, "drawable", context.packageName)
}

// FilePath : ../drawable/app_my_bg_drawable.xml    
// Call function as: val fileDrawable = getDrawableByFileName(context, "app_my_bg_drawable")
fun getDrawableByFileName(context: Context, fileName: String): Drawable? {
    return ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, context.resources.getIdentifier(fileName, "drawable", context.packageName))
}
```